# Background-image не работает/не отображается

Tags: html, css

Хочу вставить две картинки на бекграунд. Не могу понять, что не так делаю, вроде бы пути указаны правильно, другая подобная картинка в информационном блоке работает, а бекграунд не ставится. Я совсем желторотик в верстке, надеюсь на вашу помощь
Линк на css и html код: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8ImR.jpg

Comment: Ссылка на код картинкой… вы б его ещё в doc-файл положили и в zip заархивировали…

Comment: У вас "background: hsl();" перебивает "background-image". Вам следует hsl вписывать в background-image после картинок так же через запятую при этом изменив backgroun-image на background. Прикол ведь в том, что у одного элемента может быть лишь один background и не важно background-image это или просто background. Вообще можете не использовать background-image, так как просто background может принимать в себя как цвета, так картинки, так и параметры всё в одной строке. Вообще не понимаю зачем создали background-image

Comment: Либо можете задать "background: hsl(185, 75%, 39%)" псевдо-классу ":before" например растянув его на весь ".main".

Answer (score 1):

В комментариях верно подсказывают, что `background: hls(185, 75%, 39%);` перебивает ваши "разгруппированные" стили выше - `background-image`, `background-position`, `background-repeat`.
Но советы не лучше.

Всё что вам нужно сделать, это заменить проблемную строчку на:

```
background-color: hsl(185, 75%, 39%);
```

И исправить опечатку `hsl()`, а не `hls()`.

Comment: только не `hls` а `hsl` =)

Comment: @Инквизитор, спасибо, не пользуюсь этим цветом, даже не заметил опечатку)